# Comment isn't getting deleted

Tags: python, django

I made a comment model for a blog and I wanted to give the user a way to delete the comment so I made a function based view for it but it didn't work so I decided to use a class based view but both of the views give the same error. the only thing that happens is that the url gets a `?` after it and the page just refreshes as it is. The function based and class based views are both given below

func based

```
def comment_delete(request, pk):
    comment_to_delete=get_object_or_404(comment,pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        post_url=comment_to_delete.content_object.get_absolute_url()
        comment_to_delete.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Your comment has been deleted')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(post_url)

    context={
        'comment':comment_to_delete
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/confirm_delete.html', context)
```

class based

```
class DeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = comment
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        comment= self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False
```

html of confirm page

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}



<form>
    <p>are you sure you want to delete {{ comment }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" >

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title,str(self.user.username))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Comment: Note that in Django, the recommended style is to use `Comment` for the model and use `comment` for a model instance.

Comment: You could use the `login_required` decorator to your view function and change the fetch to `comment_to_delete=get_object_or_404(comment,pk=pk, user=request.user)` to get similar functionality to the class-based-view.

Comment: @Alasdair made both the changes thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your template, not your views. You need to add `method="post"` to the form to do a POST request, and add `{% csrf_token %}` to prevent a CSRF error.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>are you sure you want to delete {{ comment }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a post request to your form. Post requests need [tokens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) to protect from [Cross Site Request Forgeries](https://www.squarefree.com/securitytips/web-developers.html#CSRF). Normally a token is passed with every post request.

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>are you sure you want to delete {{ comment }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" >
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation links. helped alot!!